# SyntaxError: Unexpected token V

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I know this is a commonly asked question but I need to know theory wise, why this is happening?

I am trying to parse two encrypted values to my service.

**Javascript**

```
      var encryptedlogin = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(Email), key,  
                {  
                    keySize: 128 / 8,  
                    iv: iv,  
                    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,  
                    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7  
                });  


                var encryptedpassword = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(PasswordTwo), key,  
                {  
                    keySize: 128 / 8,  
                    iv: iv,  
                    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,  
                    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7  
                });  


             var c = String(encryptedlogin);
             var d = String(encryptedpassword); 

             var json = JSON.parse(c);
             var json1 = JSON.parse(d);

            $http.get("http://localhost:53101/TruckService.svc/validateUserA/" + json + '|' + json1 )
           .success(function(data) {});
           .error(function(data) {});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var json = JSON.parse('"' + c + '"');
var json1 = JSON.parse('"' + d + '"');
```

JSON strings must be in double quotes

Why do you need to turn it into JSON?

By the look of your get request, you could just do:

```
$http.get("http://localhost:53101/TruckService.svc/validateUserA/" + encodeURIComponent(c + '|' + d))
       .success(function(data) {});
       .error(function(data) {});
```

Or your url may be in the format of

```
"http://localhost:53101/TruckService.svc/validateUserA/?parameterName=" + encodeURIComponent(c + '|' + d)
```

Comment: I am having trouble for some reason to parse encrypted values through to my service, so I want to send it as a json object.

Comment: this is my error: ` GET http://localhost:53101/TruckService.svc/validateUserA/VWoK455BEzavGJknGdT0wA==/KCAMhT0PxC7ehxyhqUR/GA== 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: You need to pass them as parameters as you are doing it on the get string.  What address is your api expecting as it looks like you are not using the correct url.  You may also nee to encode your encrypted data (ensuring your service decodes them again). I have updated the answer for the encoding bit

Comment: yeah I know I should use post but I am new to angularjs so I just worked around it with a get and then handling it from the service.  But if I send a normal string the link works that is not the issue

Comment: See my edit, but looking at your url, your js is failing because of the double quotes in the first part of my answer

Comment: Why do you use the `?parameterName=` ?

Comment: Because I'm not sure how your service is expecting the url to be formatted or the parameters to be passed in

Comment: there is no change in the result I still get a 404 error my link:`http://localhost:53101/TruckService.svc/validateUserA/?parameterName=VWoK455BEzavGJknGdT0wA%3D%3D%7CC5P5%2BbngoMDqPlN8YDg%2BoA%3D%3D`

Comment: You need to look at your service endpoints and make sure that there is a page / url for what you are trying to hit, and make sure it will accept get (not post).  What is your service written in? 404 is page not found so there is something wrong with the url you are going to

Comment: It is a WCF RESTful service C#, but I can send data and use it in my service using this method.. my only issue is when sending encrypted values and I expect it is something to do with string format being miss read in the url..

Answer (score 0):

try to use
 '/' instead of '|'

```
$http.get("http://localhost:53101/TruckService.svc/validateUserA/" + json + '/' + json1 )
```

Comment: It does not change the output at all. The issue seems to start at the first `json` object.